# bootstrap carousel slide data from jquery array

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i am trying to create a bootstrap carousel from a jquery array. I'm very green at jquery/javascript, so I hope you all dont mind my never ending questions. My code looks like this, but its not working.... see http://jsfiddle.net/AS9tz/

```
var slideshowProperties = new Array("5039812", "5046893", "5020260");
var list = $( ".carousel-indicators" );
var item = $(".carousel-inner");

$.each(slideshowProperties, function( intIndex, objValue ){
        list.append($( '<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="' +intIndex+ '"</li>' ));
        item.append($('<div class="item"><img src="http://placehold.it/1024&text=placehold.SLIDE - '+intIndex+'"></div>'));

    }
};
```

i also need to figure out how to add class="active" to the first instance of each item?

Comment: You have syntax errors that's all... http://jsfiddle.net/AS9tz/2/

Comment: thanks...didnt see the extra bracket

Comment: now how do i add the class active to the first instance of ever append?

Comment: suppose it is not needed, i added $('.carousel').carousel({interval: 2000}) and it starts the slideshow correctly without the active class.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like after the each

```
$('.carousel-indicators li:first').addClass('active');
$('.carousel-inner li:first').addClass('active');
```